# Conditional Probability --- Card Question

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose you have two cards: one is painted black on both sides and the other is painted black on one side and orange on the other You select a card at random and view one side.

You notice it is
black. What is the probability the other side is orange?

What I have done is following:

Card 1: $B_{1}$, $B_{2}$

Card 2: $B_{1}$, $O_{2}$

Now, we want to calculate $P(O_{2}|B_{1})$, which is $$P(O_{2}|B_{1})=\dfrac{P(B_{1}\cap O_{2})}{P(B_{1})}$$

$P(B_{1}\cap O_{2})=\dfrac{1}{2}$ as there is only $1$ card (out of $2$) giving us black and orange. $P(B_{1})=\dfrac{3}{4}$.

Therefore, the resulting conditional probability is $\dfrac{2}{3}$

However, the solution of this question telling me $\dfrac{1}{3}$ is the correct answer (without explanation, just a number).

What's wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: Problem is you consider you are seeing face $B_1$ if the card is the black card. You could see face $B_2$...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$P(B_1\cap O_2)=\frac14$, since to view a black side when the other side is orange requires first selecting the black/orange card and then viewing the black side on that card, both of which have a $\frac12$ chance of occurring.

Comment: Oh! Now I understand. Thank you so much!

Comment: Just for curiosity, can we solve this question by using Bayes Formula?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical You could, and the working would be essentially identical.

Comment: thank you so much!